# Cannot invoke Web service from URL through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, soap

I have to invoke a WS operation from JS. I have written the following code in JS-

```
function fnCallWS()
 { alert("Inside function");
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://10.216.46.185:7014/XYZService/XYZService", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {  
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

            }
        }
        var sr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
'<soap:Body>'+
    '<ns1:XYZOPERATION_IOFS_REQ xmlns:ns1="http://abc.xyz.com/service/XYZService">'+
            '<ns1:Application-Details-IO>'+
                '<ns1:LEADID>ORTEST1</ns1:LEADID>'+
            '</ns1:Application-Details-IO>'+
    '</ns1:XYZOPERATION_IOFS_REQ>'+
'</soap:Body>'+'</soap:Envelope>'; 
xmlhttp.send(sr);
}
```

My WSDL URL is like this - http://10.216.46.185:7014/XYZService/XYZService?WSDL
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong as I have already referred to various examples and in many examples, same approach is used. 
And my web service is correctly written as I can get response when I invoke using SoapUI tool.

Comment: What's the problem? Error? Wrong output? CORS issue?

Comment: I find no error in JS debugging. And there are no logs on server, so mostly webservice is not being hit.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a CORS issue after all. My Weblogic server was not configured correctly. After enabling Cross Domain option and adding allowed servers, this was resolved.